# How to filter a list of objects based on some or more fields using generics?

Tags: java, spring, list, filtering, predicate

i need to figure out if it is possible to filter by creating a method that uses the generics of a list of objects. Below is the reference object:

```
public class NetworkObject implements Serializable {
   
    private String xsiType;
    private Long id;        
    private String uid;        
    private String name;
    private String displayName;
}
```

so, I'll have a list like this:

```
List<NetworkObject> networkObjectList = new ArrayList<>(); 
NetworkObject n1 = new NetworkObject();
n1.setXsiType("test1");
n1.setId(1L);
n1.setUid("1234");
n1.setName("test1");
n1.setDisplayName("disp1");
NetworkObject n2 = new NetworkObject();
n2.setXsiType("test2");
n2.setId(2L);
n2.setUid("4321");
n2.setName("test2");
n2.setDisplayName("disp2");
networkObjectList.add(n1);
networkObjectList.add(n2);
```

In the input I will receive an object of the same type of NetworkObject which may have none, one or more fields validated. And so I will have to filter the list based on those fields. I'm only interested in the case where the fields are the same. For example:

```
NetworkObject filter = new NetworkObject();
filter.setXsiType("test2");
filter.setId(2L);
filter.setUid("4321");
filter.setName(null);
filter.setDisplayName(null);
```

In this case as a result I expect object n2.

Comment: Shouldn't you simply implement an `equals` method for `NetworkObject`?

Comment: no because soon I will also have to implement "like" methods, so for example if the id is contained in the id of the object and so on.

Comment: `equals` may not suffice, but you can still build your own `boolean matches(NetworkObject other)` method that can ignore fields where one side is `null` etc.

Comment: can you give me a practical example?